# F# How Async<'T> cancellation works?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, cancellation, f#-async

I was pretty comfortable with how async cancellations where done in C# with the TPL, but I am a little bit confused in F#. Apparently by calling `Async.CancelDefaultToken()` is enough to cancel outgoing `Async<'T>` operations. But they are not cancelled as I expected, they just... vanishes... I cannot detect properly the cancellation and tear down the stack properly.

For example, I have this code that depends on a C# library that uses TPL:

```
type WebSocketListener with
  member x.AsyncAcceptWebSocket = async {
    let! client = Async.AwaitTask <| x.AcceptWebSocketAsync Async.DefaultCancellationToken
    if(not(isNull client)) then
        return Some client
    else 
        return None
  }

let rec AsyncAcceptClients(listener : WebSocketListener) =
  async {
    let! result = listener.AsyncAcceptWebSocket
    match result with
        | None -> printf "Stop accepting clients.\n"
        | Some client ->
            Async.Start <| AsyncAcceptMessages client
            do! AsyncAcceptClients listener
  }
```

When the `CancellationToken` passed to `x.AcceptWebSocketAsync` is cancelled, returns `null`, and then `AsyncAcceptWebSocket` method returns `None`. I can verify this with a breakpoint.

But, `AsyncAcceptClients` (the caller), never gets that `None` value, the method just ends, and `"Stop accepting clients.\n"` is never displayed on the console. If I wrap everything in a `try\finally` :

```
let rec AsyncAcceptClients(listener : WebSocketListener) =
  async {
    try
        let! result = listener.AsyncAcceptWebSocket
        match result with
            | None -> printf "Stop accepting clients.\n"
            | Some client ->
                Async.Start <| AsyncAcceptMessages client
                do! AsyncAcceptClients listener
   finally
        printf "This message is actually printed"
  }
```

Then what I put in the `finally` gets executed when `listener.AsyncAcceptWebSocket` returns `None`, but the code I have in the `match` still doesn't. (Actually, it prints the message on the `finally` block once for each connected client, so maybe I should move to an iterative approach?)

However, if I use a custom `CancellationToken` rather than `Async.DefaultCancellationToken`, everything works as expected, and the `"Stop accepting clients.\n"` message is print on screen.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two things about the question:

- First, when a cancellation happens in F#, the `AwaitTask` does not return `null`, but instead, the task throws `OperationCanceledException` exception. So, you do not get back `None` value, but instead, you get an exception (and then F# also runs your `finally` block).

  The confusing thing is that cancellation is a special kind of exception that cannot be handled in user code inside the `async` block - once your computation is cancelled, it cannot be un-cancelled and it will always stop (you can do cleanup in `finally`). You can workaround this (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274986/async-catch-doesnt-work-on-operationcanceledexceptions)) but it might cause unexpected things.
- Second, I would not use default cancellation token - that's shared by all async workflows and so it might do unexpected things. You can instead use `Async.CancellationToken` which gives you access to a current cancellation token (which F# automatically propagates for you - so you do not have to pass it around by hand as you do in C#).

**EDIT**: Clarified how F# async handles cancellation exceptions.

Comment: About your first point, maybe I did not explain myself correctly. `AcceptWebSocketAsync` is a method declared inside a C# library that accepts a `CancellationToken`. When the cancellation is triggered, that method returns `null` rather than a `WebSocket`. This is specifically designed this way.

Comment: @vtortola I clarified how F# handles this - but basically, once the token is cancelled, F# async will not let you continue running the async workflow (it cannot be un-cancelled). So, if you really want to continue the workflow, I'd create a separate `CancellationTokenSource` just for the method (and not pass it to `Async.Start`)

Comment: I see, thanks for that. I am still wrapping my head around this.

Comment: I got a bit confused too when writing the answer :-). But I think the key point (*once workflow is cancelled, it cannot be uncancelled*) makes good sense. So you need more advanced management of cancellation tokens.

Comment: Actually, if I create a custom token and pass it to `Async.Start` it happens exactly the same that with `Asyn.DefaultCancellationToken`. I was told there would be nice parallel programming, but so far I don't feel very comfortable about what I do in F#, I hope it is a matter of time :) Cheers.

Comment: Well, yes, if you create a custom token and pass it to `Async.Start` then the workflow gets cancelled (when the token is cancelled) and only `finally` blocks will run during the cleanup.

So you'd need a separate token for that one method (and then do not pass it to `Async.Start` if you do not want to cancel the workflow).

Comment: `final` block? is that a typo? did you mean `finally` block?

Comment: @knocte Thanks, fixed!