# Canceled Task does not return control to async block

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task, cancellation, mailboxprocessor

I tried to reduce this to the smallest possible repro, but it's still a bit long-ish, my apologies.

I have an F# project that references a C# project with code like the following.

```cs
public static class CSharpClass {
    public static async Task AsyncMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

Here's the F# code.

```ml
type Message = 
    | Work of CancellationToken
    | Quit of AsyncReplyChannel<unit>

let mkAgent() = MailboxProcessor.Start <| fun inbox -> 
    let rec loop() = async {
        let! msg = inbox.TryReceive(250)
        match msg with
        | Some (Work cancellationToken) ->
            let! result = 
                CSharpClass.AsyncMethod(cancellationToken)
                |> Async.AwaitTask
                |> Async.Catch
            // THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED AFTER CANCELLATION
            match result with
            | Choice1Of2 _ -> printfn "Success"
            | Choice2Of2 exn -> printfn "Error: %A" exn    
            return! loop()
        | Some (Quit replyChannel) -> replyChannel.Reply()
        | None -> return! loop()
    }
    loop()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let agent = mkAgent()
    use cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
    agent.Post(Work cts.Token)
    printfn "Press any to cancel."
    System.Console.Read() |> ignore
    cts.Cancel()
    printfn "Cancelled."
    agent.PostAndReply Quit
    printfn "Done."
    System.Console.Read()
```

The issue is that, upon cancellation, control never returns to the async block. I'm not sure if it's hanging in `AwaitTask` or `Catch`. Intuition tells me it's blocking when trying to return to the previous sync context, but I'm not sure how to confirm this. I'm looking for ideas on how to troubleshoot this, or perhaps someone with a deeper understanding here can spot the issue.

#### POSSIBLE SOLUTION

```ml
let! result = 
    Async.FromContinuations(fun (cont, econt, _) ->
        let ccont e = econt e
        let work = CSharpClass.AsyncMethod(cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask
        Async.StartWithContinuations(work, cont, econt, ccont))
    |> Async.Catch
```

Comment: `OperationCanceledException` has special handling in F#, always stops the whole async process, all the way up to the turtles. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27022315/180286

Comment: This is true even though a unique cancellation token is passed to the C# method, and not shared by any of the F# async code?

Comment: Yes. It's not a matter of token, it's just how `OperationCanceledException` is handled. You can even throw it yourself, without involving a token, and it will still stop the whole async.

Comment: I updated my question with a solution gleaned from the answer you linked to, which seems to work. Is this the ideal means of catching cancellation exceptions?

Comment: D'know, depends on your definition of "ideal". I really can't tell you any more than is described in those answers.

Comment: @Daniel Did the alternate solution work out for you?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine. The only reason I went with this instead of your solution is because sometimes the task-returning method returns null.

Comment: The example uses a `TaskCompletionSource<unit>`, which essentially returns a null result

Comment: I'm not seeing any other cases where it returns null. If you could clarify, I'll edit the answer for future reference.

Comment: If I wasn't clear, it's the C# method in my example that can sometimes return null, so calling `ContinueWith` would throw a NRE. `Async.AwaitTask >> Async.Catch` handles that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ultimately causes this behavior is that cancellations are special in F# Async. Cancellations effectively translate to a [stop and teardown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvKY8FJY0Qk). As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1561), cancellation in the `Task` makes it all the way out of the computation.

If you want the good old `OperationCanceledException` which you can handle as part of your computation, we can just make our own.

```
type Async =
    static member AwaitTaskWithCancellations (task: Task<_>) =
        Async.FromContinuations(fun (setResult, setException, setCancelation) ->
            task.ContinueWith(fun (t:Task<_>) -> 
                match t.Status with 
                | TaskStatus.RanToCompletion -> setResult t.Result
                | TaskStatus.Faulted -> setException t.Exception
                | TaskStatus.Canceled -> setException <| OperationCanceledException()
                | _ -> ()
            ) |> ignore
        )
```

Cancellation is now just another exception - and exceptions, we can handle.
Here's the repro:

```
let tcs = TaskCompletionSource<unit>()
tcs.SetCanceled()

async { 
    try        
        let! result = tcs.Task |> Async.AwaitTaskWithCancellations
        return result
    with
         | :? OperationCanceledException -> 
           printfn "cancelled"      
         | ex -> printfn "faulted %A" ex

    ()
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```